# How to print a report from a particular date to a particular date in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, report, odoo-9, odoo-10

This is my code for wizard and print action in python:

```
class Paymentwizard(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'payment.wizard'
_description = 'Make Payment'

date_from = fields.Date('From Date')
date_to = fields.Date('To Date')
employee_id = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', 'name')


@api.multi
def action_print(self):
date_from = self.date_from
date_to = self.date_to
name = self.employee_id 

name = self.env['loan.form'].search([('date','>=',date_from),
('date','<=',date_to),("employee_id","=",name.name)])
```

How to print the records in the name field?

or help me improve this code

Thank you

Comment: Have you created a report?

Comment: No i didn't create a report@jo541.

Comment: It will be a good learning for me if you tell me how to do this python coding @jo541

Comment: It's important to know, What would you want print? (Report of odoo, custom report ?). From which module? For which record ?

Comment: I want to print a custom report for my module named loan management. In that module i have to print the loan statement of my customers from a particular date to a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

To print your report. You must do like this.

```
class Paymentwizard(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'payment.wizard'
_description = 'Make Payment'

date_from = fields.Date('From Date')
date_to = fields.Date('To Date')
employee_id = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', 'name')
pdf = fields.Binary(string='Pdf report')

@api.multi
def action_print(self):
    record_ids = self.env['loan.form'].search([('date', '>=', self.date_from),
          ('date', '<=', self.date_to),("employee_id", "=",self.employe_id.id)]).ids
    self.pdf = self.env['report'].get_pdf(res_ids, ['your_report_xml_id'])
```

In this example. In the first time, I search all the records must be printing. After I generated my pdf with two information, the records will be printing and the xml id of the report.

The method get_pdf will return a base64 pdf. I set it in the binary field because to download the pdf, the user must click on the binary field link.

Answer (score -2):

```
self.env.cr.execute(""" select column from loan_form where date >= '%s' and date <= '%s' and employee_id in '%s'"""%(self.date_from,self.date_to,tuple(employee_id.ids)))
```

Comment: Where should i add this line to my code? anna puriyara maari solunga anna. I am new to this field.@KLN

Comment: i given full of my code to you previous question..what to do

Comment: Ok can you please modify and send me according to my code @KLN

Comment: did you know to work with pdf template and writing data

Comment: Yes I Know @KLN

Comment: I am creating a Bank module, where the customers can buy loans from the bank. In that module I want to print a report. Before printing,i want to filter the dates. I want to filter it by giving From date to To date.

Comment: What?@KLN speak in tamil itself bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156656/discussion-between-kln-and-naveen).

Comment: KLN, used the SQL request is not a great idea. Odoo as a power ORM to working with data. Use a Sql request pass all the checking of access right. The Sql request can be used in the specific case, only.

Comment: Please review [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @jo541 but odoo orm takes little bit more to execution, is it true?